# Measure metrics from CsvSink for Rate source

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I was trying to measure the performance metrics for spark structured streaming. But I am unable to see any data in the metrics log files. My input source is the [Rate source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#creating-streaming-dataframes-and-streaming-datasets) which generates data at the specified number of rows per second. Here is the link to my [code](https://gist.github.com/kudhru/e1ce6b3f399c546be5eeb1f590087992) and [metrics.properties](https://gist.github.com/kudhru/5d8a8f4d53c766e9efad4de2ae9b82d6) file.

When I run the above mentioned code using `spark-submit`, I see that the metrics logs (for example, run_1.driver.spark.streaming.aggregates.inputRate-total.csv) are created under the specified directory but most of the values are 0. 
Below is a portion of the inputeRate-total.csv file:

```
1529634585,0.0
1529634595,0.0
1529634605,0.0
1529634615,0.0
1529634625,0.0
1529634635,0.0
1529634645,0.0
1529634655,0.0
1529634665,0.0
1529634675,0.0
1529634685,0.0
1529634695,0.0
1529634705,0.0
1529634715,0.0
```

Any reason as to why this must be happening? Happy to share more information if that helps.

Comment: Any help would be deeply appreciated?

Comment: any update on this issue